How to wait for DB connection in a Hono/Bun application using Drizzle ORM?
As part of learning Hono and Drizzle, I'm creating a simple Web Server with Bun.
// src/index.ts
import { Hono } from "hono";
import UserRepo from "./repo/UserRepo";

const app = new Hono();

app.get("/ping", (c) => {
    return c.text("pong");
});

app.post("/user", async (c) => {
    const { name, email } = await c.req.json();
    const newUser = await UserRepo.create({ name, email });
    return c.json(newUser, 201);
});

app.onError((err, c) => {
    console.log(err);
    return c.json(err, 500);
});

export default {
    ...app,
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
};

And I have this DB, which is getting used through UserRepo. To keep it simple, I'm showing only the relevant DB code
// src/db/index.ts
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/postgres-js";
import postgres from "postgres";

const queryClient = postgres(process.env.DB_URL as string);
const db = drizzle(queryClient);

export { db };


It works as expected. But the server doesn't wait for database connection. In Express, we could do something like mongoose.connect(...).then(() => app.listen(...)), I'm trying to do something similar with this application. Searched through the Docs but could not find anything. Any help would be highly appreciated.

You can achieve what you’re trying to do with Bun.serve
dbConnect()
  .then(() => {
    Bun.serve(app);
    console.log('Server Running');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });


I solved with this


async function main() {
    try {
        await AppDataSource.initialize()
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(error);
        return process.exit(1)
    }

    Bun.serve({
        port: ENV.APP_PORT,
        fetch: app.fetch,
        
    })
    console.log(`Listening on port ${ENV.APP_HOST}:${ENV.APP_PORT}`);    
}
main()




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
